# Maven Webservices project taking a long time to build for unknown reasons

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, maven

have a very small Maven RESTful webservices project.

For reasons unknown, it is taking a lot of time to just load and run a program.

using JAX-RS for Building RESTful webservices.

Using Eclipse Luna and as usual, an external drive for reading and writing to the maven dependencies.

This was working normally earlier and used to debug also normally.

What settings can I tweak in Eclipse, to make it run/debug with minimal launch time for Debug and Run

Comment: Maybe get a profiler...

Comment: not to complicate but trying to understand how to integrate and a profiler would help??

Answer (score 2):

It's a long shot but something is timing out. Maybe a wsdl url somewhere. Or you moved to a different server that is blacklisted on a remote firewall.

We need a lot more detail. Can you run it from maven?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response @Bela Vizy. 
What more detail, were you expecting? Can build it successfully from command prompt with no issues, quickly with no time lag.

Please let me know the details you are looking for.

Comment: Updating maven depdendencies and Updating Indexes, takes a lot of time, when it comes to finishing the build process in eclipse luna

Comment: <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <port>8080</port>

Comment: disabled all the checks in windows preferences for Maven in Eclipse Luna, seems to work